# Read a matrix from a text file in c#

Tags: c#, matrix, text, text-files

I need to read a text file that contains the matrix, instead of having it on the code like I have, but I tried and I can't figure it out.
I have the matrix on a text file like I have on the code, but without the comas

This is a dijkstra program that reads the matrix in order to find the shortest path, thank you

```
{

    private static int MinimumDistance(int[] distance, bool[] shortestPathTreeSet, int verticesCount)
    {
        int min = int.MaxValue;
        int minIndex = 0;

        for (int v = 0; v < verticesCount; ++v)
        {
            if (shortestPathTreeSet[v] == false && distance[v] <= min)
            {
                min = distance[v];
                minIndex = v;
            }
        }

        return minIndex;
    }

    private static void Print(int[] distance, int verticesCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Vertex    Distance from source");

        for (int i = 0; i < verticesCount; ++i)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t  {1}", i, distance[i]);
    }

    public static void DijkstraAlgo(int[,] graph, int source, int verticesCount)
    {
        int[] distance = new int[verticesCount];
        bool[] shortestPathTreeSet = new bool[verticesCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < verticesCount; ++i)
        {
            distance[i] = int.MaxValue;
            shortestPathTreeSet[i] = false;
        }

        distance[source] = 0;

        for (int count = 0; count < verticesCount - 1; ++count)
        {
            int u = MinimumDistance(distance, shortestPathTreeSet, verticesCount);
            shortestPathTreeSet[u] = true;

            for (int v = 0; v < verticesCount; ++v)
                if (!shortestPathTreeSet[v] && Convert.ToBoolean(graph[u, v]) && distance[u] != int.MaxValue && distance[u] + graph[u, v] < distance[v])
                    distance[v] = distance[u] + graph[u, v];
        }

        Print(distance, verticesCount);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] graph =  {
                     { 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0 },
                     { 6, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0 },
                     { 0, 9, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 2 },
                     { 0, 0, 5, 0, 9, 16, 0, 0, 0 },
                     { 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0 },
                     { 0, 0, 6, 0, 10, 0, 2, 0, 0 },
                     { 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 2, 0, 1, 6 },
                     { 9, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5 },
                     { 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5, 0 }
                        };

        DijkstraAlgo(graph, 0, 9);
    }
}
```

}

and here is the text file matrix:

0 6 8 12 0 0 0 0 0 0
6 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0
8 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
12 5 1 0 9 10 14 16 15 0
0 0 0 9 0 0 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 13 0
0 0 0 14 3 0 0 3 0 6
0 0 0 16 0 0 3 0 1 4
0 0 0 15 0 13 0 1 0 7
0 0 0 0 0 0 6 4 7 0

Comment: Share the text matrix you have in text file.

Comment: added thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you correctly.

You are after a way to read a space deliminated `int`s from a file and convert it into a multidimensional (square) array of `int`. e.g `int[,]`

You could do something like this

**Given**

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static T[,] ToRectangularArray<T>(this IReadOnlyList<T[]> arrays)
   {
      var ret = new T[arrays.Count, arrays[0].Length];
      for (var i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
         for (var j = 0; j < arrays[0].Length; j++)           
            ret[i, j] = arrays[i][j];
      return ret;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var someArray = File.ReadAllLines("myAwesomeFile")   // read from File
                    .Select(x => x.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()) // split line into array of int
                    .ToArray()                       // all to array
                    .ToRectangularArray();           // send to multidimensional array
```